# Search for a word in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

If I am looking for a particular word inside a string, for example, in the string "how are you" I am looking for "are".
 Would a regular indexOf() work faster and better or a Regex match()

```
String testStr = "how are you";
String lookUp = "are";

//METHOD1
if (testStr.indexOf(lookUp) != -1)
{
 System.out.println("Found!");
}

//OR
//METHOD 2
if (testStr.match(".*"+lookUp+".*"))
{
 System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

Which of the two methods above is a better way of looking for a string inside another string? Or is there a much better alternative?

- Ivard

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3876246/450398

Comment: In the j2se 1.6 the new method is String.maches instead of http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't care whether it's actually the entire word you're matching, then `indexOf()` will be a lot faster.

If, on the other hand, you need to be able to differentiate between `are`, `harebrained`, `aren't` etc., then you need a regex: `\bare\b` will only match `are` as an entire word (`\\bare\\b` in Java).

`\b` is a word boundary anchor, and it matches the empty space between an alphanumeric character (letter, digit, or underscore) and a non-alphanumeric character.

Caveat: This also means that if your search term isn't actually a word (let's say you're looking for `###`), then these word boundary anchors will only match in a string like `aaa###zzz`, but not in `+++###+++`.

Further caveat: Java has by default a limited worldview on what constitutes an alphanumeric character. Only ASCII letters/digits (plus the underscore) count here, so word boundary anchors will fail on words like `élève`, `relevé` or `ärgern`. [Read more about this (and how to solve this problem) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Method one should be faster because it has lesser overhead. if it is about performance in searching in huge files a specialized method like [boyer moore pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) could lead to further improvements.

Comment: For so e reason the link isn't displayed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: The dash in `Boyer-Moore` was really an en-dash (`U+2013`).  I don't know offhand if that's legal in a URL, but SO doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fixed string, not a pattern, as in the example in your question, `indexOf` will be better (simpler) and faster, since it does not need to use regular expressions.

Also, if the string you are searching for does contain characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions, with `indexOf` you don't need to worry about escaping these characters.

In general, use `indexOf` where possible, and `match` for pattern matching, where `indexOf` cannot do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking up one **string** inside another you should be using `indexOf` or `contains` method. Example: See if `"foo"` is present in a string.

But if you are looking for a **pattern** use the `match` method.
Example: See if `"foo"` is present at the *beginning/end* of the string. Or see if it's present as a *whole* word.

Using the `match` method for simple string searching is not efficient because of the regex engine overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is faster and since it's not a complex expressions there is no reason to use regex here.

Answer (score 0):

of course `indexOf()`is better than `match()`.
one 'match()'  consists of many compares: a==a,r==r ,e==e ;
at the same time,you append wildcards which would be divided into many cases:

1. ?are
   ??are
   ???are
   ????are
   ........
   are    are?    are??    are???

until it's as long as the original strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question practically answers itself; if you have to *ask* whether regex is the better choice, it almost certainly isn't.  Also, when you're choosing between regex and non-regex solutions, performance should never be your primary criterion.  Wait until you've got some working code and profile it.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to compare the both versions is to analyze the source code of indexOf method and the regex.matches methods itself, calculating runtime of both the algorithm implementations in Big_O_notation and comparing their best, average and worst cases (charsequence found at start, middle or end of the string respectively). The source code goes here [indexOf_source](http://tinypaste.com/f993e) and here [regex.matches](http://tinypaste.com/a76f28). We need to do a run-time analysis of both to see what it is exactly doing. Hectic task but it's the only way to make a true comparison, the rest of them being only assumptions. Good question though.

Answer (score 0):

I use it:

```
public boolean searchStr(String search, String what) {
    if(!search.replaceAll(what,"_").equals(search)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example use:

```
String s = "abc";
String w = "bc";
if(searchStr(s,w)) { 
    //this returns true
}
s="qwe";
w="asd";
if(searchStr(s,w)) { 
    //this returns false
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.