# Remove certain instance of a specific item from a string

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a way to remove a specific instance of an item from a string? For example, if I have the string:

```
"kiwi, durian, and, starfruit"
```

how can I remove the final comma only? I need a solution that will remove the last comma from the string no matter how many items the string contains.

Couldn't find anything at all on this by Googling around (at least not for Ruby without Rails.  If you're using Rails, it's easy--just use the `array.to_sentence` method.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, you need to show where you've searched and why those didn't apply, or show code you've tried and explain why it doesn't work. As is, it looks like you're asking us to write something for you, and Stack Overflow isn't a "write code for me site". Instead, we help you debug problems in your code.

Comment: @theTinMan Understood, I added what I tried as well as a solution I found for anyone using Rails.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-sub) like this:

```
"kiwi, durian, and, starfruit".sub(/,([^,]*)\z/, '\1')
#=> "kiwi, durian, and starfruit"
```

Comment: Worth a special commendation as a code golf worthy answer! nice one.

Comment: `$1` doesn't do here what you think it does. You want `'\1'`. Also what about non-word chars?

Comment: `gsub` is slower than `sub`.

Answer (score 2):

You could `reverse` the string, `sub` a comma for `""`, and `reverse` it again.
But `rindex`is nice too:

```
str = "kiwi, durian, and, starfruit"
str.slice!(str.rindex(","))

p str # => "kiwi, durian, and starfruit"
```

Comment: @theTinMan I agree, `[]=` is better.

Comment: Speedwise, they're a wash. I checked with Fruity and it says the speed difference is negligible so it probably comes down to team programming style and programmer's choice. Plus, avoiding the use of a regular expression improves the speed over regex-based `sub` and `gsub`.

Comment: This will bomb for a string with no commas. Also I think we're underestimating regex performance. Regex is very fast.

Comment: This returned `","` for me.  The only answer that worked was the one I marked as correct.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Keren it reurns a comma and it modifies `str`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
"kiwi, durian, and, starfruit".sub /(.*),/, '\1'
#=> "kiwi, durian, and starfruit"
```

it works because the `.*` is greedy

Comment: While `sub` is faster than `gsub`, relying on a regex is costly unless the regex is anchored. And, even then, they tend to lose-out to using the built-in methods.

Comment: @the Tin Man - it's not a race! :) also I don't know why you think an anchor would help but I guess it couldn't hurt.

Comment: I think anchors help because I've tested patterns with and without them, and there's a major speed-up if the engine knows to start at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're misunderstanding something fundamental. The regex engine always starts at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I know that it starts at the beginning. If the value we're after is at or near the end, then an anchor can make a huge difference, especially for long strings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686139/finding-if-a-sentence-contains-a-specific-phrase-in-ruby/4687005#4687005.

Comment: How are we supposed to know where it is? The problem with your benchmarks is that you load them for specific strings, so it's not a real-world case. Also you should add `rindex`, I think you'll be surprised how it does.

Comment: `rindex` is tested. We can't always know what we're searching for, but often we have ideas. If we can't tell in advance we use the fastest generic search. If we have an idea where what we want is at the start or end we can use the search that favors one or the other. Not knowing this information means we're shooting in the dark. Knowing means we can make informed decisions.

Comment: I guess I just don't see the point of these anti-regex mental gymnastics, especially since all the non-regex answers offered here are broken.

Answer (score 0):

String to array split on the commas, then re join all but the last items with a comma and add the final part of the array back on.

```
string = "kiwi, durian, and, starfruit"
array = string.split","
pre = array.slice(0,array.length - 1).join","
post = array[array.length - 1]
output = pre + post
p = output
```

Answer (score 0):

There being five answers over nine hours, all that's left are crumbs. Here's one:

```
str = "kiwi, durian, and, starfruit"

str[str[/.*,/].size-1] = ''
str #=> "kiwi, durian, and tarfruit"
```

Answer (score -1):

If the string always includes "and" you could use `gsub`.

```
new_string = "kiwi, durian, and, starfruit".gsub("and,", "and")
```

Otherwise you could write a function like this:

```
def strip_last_comma string
  spt_str = string.split(",")
  string = spt_str[0..spt_str.size-2].join(",") + spt_str.last
end
```

Comment: `gsub` will *always* run slower than using `sub` when you're only replacing one thing.

Comment: I don't know if sub is really faster than gsub but it's useful as a clue that we're only replacing one thing.

Comment: "I don't know if sub is really faster than gsub...". Benchmarks show us these things. Sometimes the situation somewhat nullifies the advantage, such as when replacing something at the end of a string, however, in general `sub` only tries to replace once, where `gsub` will try at least once more and if the string being searched is really long and the first hit was at the start, the resulting second search will waste CPU.