# How to verify that the last character in a string is a number

Tags: ruby

I need to check if the last character in a string is a digit, and if so, increment it.

I have a directory structure of `/u01/app/oracle/...` and that's where it goes off the rails. Sometimes it ends with the version number, sometimes it ends with `dbhome_1` (or `2`, or `3`), and sometimes, I have to assume, it will take some other form. If it ends with `dbhome_X`, I need to parse that and bump that final digit, if it is a digit.

I use `split` to split the directory structure on '/', and use `include?` to check if the final element is something like "dbhome". As long as my directory structure ends with `dbhome_X` it seems to work. As I was testing, though, I tried a path that ended with `dbhome`, and found that my check for the last character being a digit didn't work.

```
db_home = '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome'

if db_home.split('/')[-1].include?('dbhome')
  homedir=db_home.split('/')[-1]
  if homedir[-1].to_i.is_a? Numeric
    homedir=homedir[0...-1]+(homedir[-1].to_i+1).to_s
    new_path="/"+db_home.split('/')[1...-1].join("/")+"/"+homedir.to_s
  end
else
  new_path=db_home+"/dbhome_1"
end

puts new_path
```

I did not expect the output to be `/u01/app/oracle/11.2.0/product/dbhom1` - it seems to have fallen into the `if` block that added `1` to the final character.

If I set the initial path to `/u01/app/.../dbhome_1`, I get the expected `/u01/app/.../dbhome_2` as the output.

Comment: `String#to_i` returns 0 if the string does not start with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to make matching a tad bit easier

`if !!(db_home[/.*dbhome.*\z]) ..`

Comment: Ruby amateur here. I tend to consider regexp a tool of last resort because (in sql at least) it is more expensive than other matching options. Unfortunately I'm too new to ruby - not sure if that was supposed to be a full example, or... but if I replace my first if with that, I get a "warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /.*dbhome.*\z])

Comment: @stephan, that's the proper way to think of regular expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687005/128421 for some experiments I did with different versions of Ruby and variations on how to search text. Regex are extremely powerful and when used carefully can reduce the code written greatly. Used improperly they can introduce bugs that can reduce a program to a crawl or break it, both in ways that are extremely hard to debug. Most people look at them like some magical panacea or a hammer to hit everything with when learning. They're just another tool in the toolbox to be used surgically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex's

```
/[0-9]$/.match("How3").nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check if the last character in a string is a digit, and if
>   so, increment it.

This is one option:

```
s = 'string9'

s[-1].then { |last| last.to_i.to_s == last ? [s[0..-2], last.to_i+1].join : s }

#=> "string10"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome'.sub(/\d\z/) { |s| s.succ }
  #=> "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome"
```

```
'/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome9'.sub(/\d\z/) { |s| s.succ }
  #=> "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome10"
```

Comment: "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome9".succ #=> "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhomf0" , but "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome_9".succ #=> "/u01/app/11.2.0/dbhome_10" . Rather surprised myself.

Comment: @steenslag, the doc [String#succ](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-succ) confirms the first's behavior, but not the second's. I'm always hesitant to suggest that some behaviour is a Ruby bug, but I can't explain it. This is unrelated to my answer. Right?

Comment: I think it is just Ruby trying to be nice. And I discovered it while trying to improve on your answer; it is not meant as criticism.

Comment: Very interesting. Perhaps there's a clue here in the doc: "Incrementing nonalphanumerics uses the underlying character set's collating sequence.

If the increment generates a “carry,'' the character to the left of it is incremented. This process repeats until there is no carry, adding an additional character if necessary."? If there is "no carry" in a nonalphanumeric character set's collating sequence, then perhaps alphanumeric characters to the right of it are incremented as necessary. I find that `'*z9'.succ` returns `'*aa0'`, for example, while `'*'.succ` returns `'+'`. (cont)

Comment: I also find that `'*z9*`.succ` returns `'*aa0*`, among other tests. So, it looks like if there is a combination of nonalphanumeric and alphanumeric characters, `succ` will increment the rightmost sequence of alphanumeric characters not interrupted by any nonalphanumeric characters, while if there are no alphanumeric characters, `succ` will increment the `ord` value of the rightmost nonalphanumeric character and return the resulting character.

Comment: @BobRodes, I'm too sleepy to get my head around that right now, but will have another look at it tomorrow (Saturday).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just a hypothesis as to why it seems more like a feature than a bug to me. But I'd say that the important thing is testing how `succ` works if you need to use it! :) I never tried doing all that stuff with it before.

Comment: @BobRodes, yes, that seems to be the case. `s = 'a8'` seems to be treated as `ss = 'ay': s = s.succ #=> "a9"; s.succ #"b0"`, whereas `ss  = ss.succ #=> "az" ; ss.succ #=> "ba"`. That is, the `'8'` is treated just as a letter. By contrast, if the trailing digits are preceded by certain other characters (e.g., and underscore or space), `succ` causes the digits to increase by one even if it means adding another digit (e.g., `s = "a_9"; s.succ #=> "a_10"`). Let's try another `s = '@9'; s.succ #=> "@10"`. Note `255.chr.succ.ord  #=> 1`.

Comment: That last note is interesting, and something not to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a starting point if you're running Ruby v2.6+:

```
fname = 'filename1'

fname[/\d+$/].then { |digits|
  fname[/\d+$/] = digits.to_i.next.to_s if digits
}

fname # => "filename2"
```

And it's safe if the filename doesn't end with a digit:

```
fname = 'filename'

fname[/\d+$/].then { |digits|
  fname[/\d+$/] = digits.to_i.next.to_s if digits
}

fname # => "filename"
```

I'm not sure if I like doing it that way better than the more traditional way which works with much older Rubies:

```
digits = fname[/\d+$/]
fname[/\d+$/] = digits.to_i.next.to_s if digits
```

except for the fact that `digits` gets stuck into the variable space after only being used once. There's probably worse things that happen in my code though.

This is taking advantage of String's [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) methods.

Comment: I didn't get the first option to work - it complained that "then" was an undefined method for string. But the "more traditional" option seems to be working perfectly. Obviously I've got lots to learn still. Thanks!

Comment: Your Ruby is < v2.6 as that's when that functionality was introduced.