# How to increment vowels in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to write a method called "vowel_cipher" that takes a string and returns a new string where every vowel becomes the next vowel in the alphabet.

This is what I wrote but I'm not getting the right answer:

```
def vowel_cipher(string)
  new = []
    vowels = "aeiou"
  string.each_char do |char|
if !vowels.include?(char)
  new << char
elsif 
  old_idx = vowels.index(char)
  num = old_idx + 1
  new_idx = num % vowels.length
  new << vowels[new_idx]
  end
  end
  return new_idx
    end

puts vowel_cipher("bootcamp") #=> buutcemp
puts vowel_cipher("paper cup") #=> pepir cap
```

Comment: I actually made a code golf challenge of this a few years back: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/163141/ot-wes-thi-bist-uf-tomis

Comment: @AJFaraday nice one - I used a version of it in my answer. Great artists steal and all that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This has a homework smell. If so, I'd highly recommend reading "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
VOWELS = %w[a e i o u]
NEXT_VOWELS = VOWELS.zip(VOWELS.rotate).to_h
# => {"a"=>"e", "e"=>"i", "i"=>"o", "o"=>"u", "u"=>"a"}

'jived fox nymph grabs quick waltz'.gsub(
  Regexp.union(VOWELS), # => /a|e|i|o|u/
  NEXT_VOWELS
)
# => "jovid fux nymph grebs qaock weltz"
```

The magic occurs in building a hash using [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) from the vowels, and their rotated values using [`rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate) and [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-zip), and using [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to let `gsub` search for any matches, and passing a hash to `gsub` which it will use to replace matches found.

---

Using `tr`, as mentioned by Max, is very fast and great for *single character* transformations. Using `gsub`, like Cary Swoveland and I used, will work for multi-character strings, so if you're having to replace sub-strings or words, sentences, *templates in a templating engine* then this is the starting point.

Note: `gsub` and a correctly written regex is also [extremely fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687005/128421). Use a poorly written regex and your code will slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NEXT_VOWEL = {"a"=>"e", "A"=>"E", "e"=>"i", "E"=>"I", "i"=>"o",
              "I"=>"O", "o"=>"u", "O"=>"U", "u"=>"a", "U"=>"A"}
```

```
def vowel_cipher(str)
  str.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, NEXT_VOWEL)
end
```

```
vowel_cipher "Alice in wonderland" 
  #=> "Eloci on wundirlend"
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions.

Comment: Why would you use `#gsub` which is made for pattern replacement when you can use `#tr` which is made for character translation which is exactly what we are looking for?

Comment: I actually had to benchmark this out of curiosity and your method is 78% slower than `string.tr "aAeEiIoOuU", "eEiIoOuUaA"`. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/87d022d183f87513a7669b1fda3d0911

Comment: @max, I somehow missed that in your answer. It's perfect.

Comment: `tr` is a straight call to the C code, whereas `gsub` drops into the regexp engine to process the pattern. Unanchored patterns are much slower than anchored, so dropping into the engine and not having an anchored pattern will cause a hit. See the comment at the end of my answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687005/128421