# How to check whether a string contains a substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string variable with content:

```
varMessage =   
            "hi/thsid/sdfhsjdf/dfjsd/sdjfsdn\n"


            "/my/name/is/balaji.so\n"
            "call::myFunction(int const&)\n"
            "void::secondFunction(char const&)\n"
             .
             .
             .
            "this/is/last/line/liobrary.so"
```

In the string I have to find a sub-string:

```
"hi/thsid/sdfhsjdf/dfjsd/sdjfsdn\n"

"/my/name/is/balaji.so\n"
"call::myFunction(int const&)\n"
```

How can I find it? I need to determine whether the sub-string is present or not.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876246/best-way-to-find-a-sub-string-in-a-string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878656/128421 for a breakdown of various ways to do this.

Answer (score 1614, accepted):

You can use the [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method:

```
my_string = "abcdefg"
if my_string.include? "cde"
   puts "String includes 'cde'"
end
```

Comment: Remember that `include?` is case sensetive. So if `my_string` in the example above would be something like `"abcDefg"` (with an uppercase `D`), `include?("cde")` would return `false`. You may want to do a `downcase()` before calling `include?()`.

Comment: Include on it's own is not ideal as it can throw a NoMethodError if nil

    test = nil
    test.include?("test")

NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass


should always convert the value being included to the expected value:-

    test.to_s.include?("test")

Comment: @Gary's advice holds *if* your goal is to minimize exceptions raised in this part of the code. That is not always the best goal. Generally if you expect a string at this point in the code and a value is nil instead, that implies something unexpected has occurred and an exception being raised is appropriate. If the existence of a nil here is unexpected, using `to_s` will hide the problem and increase the distance between the source and the detection of the problem, making it harder to debug.

Comment: Alternatively, avoid sending methods to nil with a safe navigation operator `test&.include?("test")`

Answer (score 107):

If case is irrelevant, then a **case-insensitive regular expression** is a good solution:

```
/bcd/i =~ 'aBcDe'   # returns nil if no match
```

or

```
/bcd/i === 'aBcDe'  # returns false if no match
```

This will also work for multi-line strings.

See Ruby's [Regexp](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Regexp.html) class for more information.

Comment: If you are matching against user input and using this technique, remember to use `Regexp.escape` on the string.  For most use cases, `some_str.include? substr.downcase()` should work faster and be more readable.

Comment: Using a regular expression this way isn't necessarily going to be faster than using `'aBcDe'.downcase.include?('bcd')`. Regex have their purpose but don't use them when the built-in methods are faster. Benchmarking with the actual data being tested can reveal much.

Comment: This does NOT evaluate as true. It evaluates to 1 which is not true.

Comment: !!('aBcDe' =~ /bcd/i) will evaluate to true or false. Use the !! idiom

Comment: alternatively, use match? to return a boolean: `/bcd/i.match?('aBcDe')`

Comment: @scrthq: Or for minimal characters for code golfing, use `===` instead, `/bcd/i==='aBcDe'`. `.match?` is definitely more descriptive for normal code though.

Answer (score 72):

You can also do this...

```
my_string = "Hello world"

if my_string["Hello"]
  puts 'It has "Hello"'
else
  puts 'No "Hello" found'
end

# => 'It has "Hello"'
```

This example uses Ruby's String [`#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

Comment: This is a neat trick I've not seen before. But `#include?` is still a little faster.

Comment: `#include?` doesn't work when you are working with sentences with spaces inside because `#include` splits the sentence in words and then uses the words as separate array values. This works perfectly for sentences. +1

Comment: See Ruby's String [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method for more information.

Comment: @luissimo `include?` does not split the string. It simply checks if a string is or isn't within an other string. `'Hello World! How are you?'.include?('e y') #=> true` This answer does the same thing. `'Hello World! How are you?'['e y'] #=> "e y"` (which is truthy), `nil` is returned if there is no match (which is falsy).

Answer (score 36):

Expanding on Clint Pachl's answer:

Regex matching in Ruby returns `nil` when the expression doesn't match. When it does, it returns the index of the character where the match happens. For example:

```
"foobar" =~ /bar/  # returns 3
"foobar" =~ /foo/  # returns 0
"foobar" =~ /zzz/  # returns nil
```

It's important to note that in Ruby only `nil` and the boolean expression `false` evaluate to false. Everything else, including an empty Array, empty Hash, or the Integer 0, evaluates to true.

That's why the `/foo/` example above works, and why.

```
if "string" =~ /regex/
```

works as expected, only entering the 'true' part of the `if` block if a match occurred.

Comment: `if( ("foobar" =~ /foo/) == nil ) puts 'Not Found' else puts 'Found' end` It should work.

Answer (score 30):

A more succinct idiom than the accepted answer above that's available in Rails (from 3.1.0 and above) is `.in?`:

```
my_string = "abcdefg"
if "cde".in? my_string
  puts "'cde' is in the String."
  puts "i.e. String includes 'cde'"
end
```

I also think it's more readable.

See the [`in?`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/Object/in%3F) documentation for more information.

Note again that it's only available in *Rails*, and not pure Ruby.

Comment: This relies on rails, the OP asked for a ruby solution

Comment: That's right, although since a significant proportion of Ruby developers are using Rails, I thought this might be a preferred solution for some due to its clarity and brevity.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239625/128421. It's in Rails, but is easily accessed from regular Ruby using Rails' [Active Support Core Extensions](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) which allow easy cherry-picking of small groups of methods such as only [`in?`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in-questionmark).

Comment: Correct @theTinMan. `"cde".in? my_string` in pure Ruby yields `NoMethodError`. But with `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion'` it works, which can be loaded either from [Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) itself or from the cut-down [Active Support Core Extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport).

Answer (score 14):

Ternary way

```
my_string.include?('ahr') ? (puts 'String includes ahr') : (puts 'String does not include ahr')
```

OR

```
puts (my_string.include?('ahr') ? 'String includes ahr' : 'String not includes ahr')
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [String Element Reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method which is `[]`

Inside the `[]` can either be a literal substring, an index, or a regex:

```
> s='abcdefg'
=> "abcdefg"
> s['a']
=> "a"
> s['z']
=> nil
```

Since `nil` is functionally the same as `false` and any substring returned from `[]` is `true` you can use the logic as if you use the method `.include?`:

```
0> if s[sub_s]
1>    puts "\"#{s}\" has \"#{sub_s}\""
1> else 
1*    puts "\"#{s}\" does not have \"#{sub_s}\""
1> end
"abcdefg" has "abc"

0> if s[sub_s]
1>    puts "\"#{s}\" has \"#{sub_s}\""
1> else 
1*    puts "\"#{s}\" does not have \"#{sub_s}\""
1> end
"abcdefg" does not have "xyz"
```

Just make sure you don't confuse an index with a sub string:

```
> '123456790'[8]    # integer is eighth element, or '0'
=> "0"              # would test as 'true' in Ruby
> '123456790'['8']  
=> nil              # correct
```

You can also use a regex:

```
> s[/A/i]
=> "a"
> s[/A/]
=> nil
```

Answer (score 4):

> How to check whether a string contains a substring in Ruby?

When you say 'check', I assume you want a boolean returned in which case you may use [`String#match?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F). `match?` accepts strings or regexes as its first parameter, if it's the former then it's automatically converted to a regex. So your use case would be:

```
str = 'string'
str.match? 'strings' #=> false
str.match? 'string'  #=> true
str.match? 'strin'   #=> true
str.match? 'trin'    #=> true
str.match? 'tri'     #=> true
```

`String#match?` has the added benefit of an optional second argument which specifies an index from which to search the string. By default this is set to `0`.

```
str.match? 'tri',0   #=> true
str.match? 'tri',1   #=> true
str.match? 'tri',2   #=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include?('substring')
  # Do something
end
```

This will help you check if the string contains substring or not

```
puts "Enter a string"
user_input = gets.chomp  # Ex: Tommy
user_input.downcase!    #  tommy


if user_input.include?('s')
    puts "Found"
else
    puts "Not found"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can not use one of the libs mentioned above, one could achieve the same with simple text search (this is ignoring cases because of `downcase`):

```
ADD_BUTTON_TEXTS = ["add to cart", "add to basket"].freeze
target_text = "AdD tO cArT"
ADD_BUTTON_TEXTS.each do |text|
  puts "Text was found" if target_text.downcase.include?(text)
end
```