# Ruby Is a string present within another string (using a regexp)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a `present?` method in ruby to check if a string is present within an other? I'd want to return as soon as a match is found since I will be checking for multiple substrings. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find substring in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258517/how-to-find-substring-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found what i was looking for (because of the use of **regexp**):

> index(regexp [, offset]) → fixnum or nil
>
> Returns the index of the
> first occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str.
> Returns nil if not found.

```
"hello".index('lo')            #=> 3
"hello".index('a')             #=> nil
"hello".index(?e)              #=> 1
"hello".index(/[aeiou]/, -3)   #=> 4
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html

i just used a loop checking if the index is nil

Comment: Just as a FYI, there are more Ruby-like ways of doing it: `'hello'['lo']` or `'hello'[/lo/]`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I think in this case i'll spend the extra 5 char nonetheless, just to make sure it's clear to everyone what is going on. 

EDIT: just to clarify for others 'hellohello'['lo'] => lo, not the index, but would still work since 'hell'['lo'] => nil

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean [include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for include?

```
"ab123de".include?("123")
```

Answer (score 0):

include?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F