# Convert String to Regexp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I frequently need to convert a String into a Regexp. For many strings, `Regexp.new(string)` is sufficient. But if `string` contains special characters, they need to be escaped:

```
string = "foo(bar)"
regex = Regexp.new(string) # => /foo(bar)/
!!regex.match(string) # => false
```

The Regexp class has a nice way to escape all characters that are special to regex: [`Regexp.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape). It's used like so:

```
string = "foo(bar)"
escaped_string = Regexp.escape(string) # => "foo\\(bar\\)"
regex = Regexp.new(escaped_string) # => /foo\(bar\)/ 
!!regex.match(string) # => true
```

This really seems like this should be the default way `Regexp.new` works. Is there a better way to convert a String to a Regexp, besides `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(string))`? This *is* Ruby, after all.

Comment: `Regexp.new` should NOT work that way, because one could not use "special" regex constructs then. Also, I think `include` will do the same job. Check [*How to check whether a string contains a substring in Ruby?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258517/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-ruby)

Comment: `String::include?` is the best way to match a `String` against another `String`, but I don't think it can output a `Regexp`. I buy your point about `Regexp.new`, though.

Comment: The point is, you do not need a `Regexp`  at all to check if a literal `String` is present inside another `String`. That is redundant complication/overhead.

Comment: Sure, but that might not be my goal. For example, if I'm using some gem whose API expects a `Regexp` as input, then neither `"foo(bar)"` nor `Regexp.new("foo(bar)")` will do the trick.

Comment: String's `[]` allows either fixed strings or regexp, as does `gsub` and `sub`. An API that is restrictive when the class itself allows either seems too rigid.

Comment: How can you use `include?` in place of `"chacha".scan(/cha/) #=> ["cha", "cha"]`? btw, `String::include?` references a class method of `String`. The reference you want (for an instance method) is `String#include?`.

Comment: Most regular expression libraries I've used take strings that represent regular expressions and if you have special characters in them then it's your responsibility to escape them either manually, or using the `escape` method. You could always patch in your own `Regexp.string` method if you like.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good catch, that comment should say `String#include?`. @tadman @theTinMan Yes, I'm starting to see your point. In most cases, converting a String to a Regex in this manner is not necessary. Let me consider if there's a way I can change the answer (or the question) so that this is useful to future visitors here. I'm sure I'm not the only person to think about this. :)

Comment: @tadman @theTinMan Does the new answer satisfy your concerns? If so, I suppose we should throw away my dangerous first answer (about `::union`)

Answer (score 2):

**You should never need to run `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(string))`** This is because, in Core and StdLib, practically every method that takes a Regexp also takes a String (as it should).

In the original case, if you're trying to match a big String `big_string` on a wacky string with special characters like `"foo(bar)"`, you can just run `big_string.match("foo(bar)")`.

If you're trying to do something fancier, you might need use both `::escape` and `::new`, but *never* in direct composition. For example, if we want to match `big_string` on a wacky string followed by a lone digit, we'll run `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(string) + "\\d")`.

Comment: Be careful here. `"\d"` is a *literal* `d` in string, but `/\d/` is a digit in a regular expression context. You need `"\\d"` in this case.

Comment: Yep, that's what I get for not testing code before posting it.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `"foo(bar)".match("foo(bar)") => nil`, but `"foo(bar)".match(Regexp.escape("foo(bar)")) => #<MatchData "foo(bar)">`