# Problems with a include or if in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im having issues with rails with the code

```
if @turno.chop == res[:department].to_s
```

where turno contains strings like ABC1 and department like ABC, im trying to filter if turno its equal of department but i need reduce the string of turno for that.
Every time what i try to do that the code dont finish and stuck in other part of code, when i delete the condition, the code works perfectly  but dont do the filter.

i tryid to to do like

```
if @turno.include?(res[:department].to_s)
```

But appears the same error.

Comment: Please be more accurate. `@turno` and `turno` mean different things in Ruby. `:department` and `department` are not the same. `ABC1` does not mean `"ABC1"`.

Comment: It sounds like the root of your question is how to see if a part of one string exists in another string? I believe `include?` would work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something very similar to this was answered in the stackoverflow.com question. [How to check whether a string contains a substring in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258517/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-ruby)

The `include?` command sounds like what you should use.

```
my_string = "abcdefg"
if my_string.include? "cde"
   puts "String includes 'cde'"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more accurate, @turno can contain a string like "ABC1" and res[:department] contains a string with "ABC" i need reduce the string in @turno to the first X characters and compare it with the content of res[:department]