# How to tell if a string contains a substring

Tags: ruby, string

I want to know if a string contains a substring.

String examples:

```
"Hey boy, the cat is in the kitchen ?"
"I want to know if the dog is in the kitchen"
```

Substring:

```
"the ... is in the kitchen"
```

But I need to ignore the words "cat, dog", how can I do that?

`string.include?` is not the right way because I want the complete sentence with "the" at the beginning.

Comment: You could use `r = /\bthe +\w+ +is in the kitchen\b/`. Then `"the cat is in the kitchen".match?(r) #=>  true` but `"the dog is in the kitchenette".match?(r) #=> false`.

Comment: Your question isn't clearly asked. What does `...` signify? The location either "cat" or "dog" MUST appear? Why isn't `include?` sufficient? It tells you if the substring occurs, and that's it. Why do you need "the" at the beginning? Are you trying to work with a regular expression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258517/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
def the_in_the_kitchen(string)
    return string.match?(/the \w+ is in the kitchen/i)
end
```

This should work. I've used a regexp, and replace the word `cat` or `dog` by `\w+`, which means a serie of letters. I've also added the `i` flag to the regexp, it stands for **i**gnore case. Hence *The DOG iS In ThE KITchen* would work as well.

Comment: Note the need for word breaks in my comment on the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I disagree, author did not specify the need for word breaks. However, the comment could be useful if it really is the case :)

Comment: OK, then let's "clothe dog in the kitchenette". We are speaking of the use of the English language. :-)