# Finding a partial string match amongst similar variants

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I'm looping through an array of string-based song titles. My goal is to find if my base title is present within the array identical titles but with possible/additional characters. I'm running into a few problems with the few techniques I'm currently using. Using `includes?` I must test both ways while downcasing:

```
"The Girl Is Mine (Paul McCartney)".downcase.include? "The Girl Is Mine" || "The Girl Is Mine".downcase.include? "The Girl Is Mine (Paul McCartney)"
```

I came across `match?` but once additional the additional characters come in things don't work.

```
"The Girl Is Mine".match? /The Girl Is Mine (feat. Paul McCartney)/i
=> false
```

The goal is to find the beginning sequence of characters, case insensitive: `"The Girl Is Mine"`. I don't really need anything to complex so if this can be done without an algorithm I'm all ears. If not I'm still all ears.

Comment: Escape special chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't agree with the dup. The asker is not looking specifically to embed a string in a regexp, they are looking for some more generic string-based search functionality (probably would still close it as too broad)

Comment: @Max See "*once additional the additional characters come in things don't work*" - the regex string contains parenetheses and a dot, these are special regex metacharacters, and these are the root cause of the question. The duplicate is good, I have added another one explaining which chars must be escaped in regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew regexs are pointless in this case. Ruby can explicitly check for substrings without constructing one. I think the asker is confused because even without special characters getting in the way, they don't seem to know what kind of strings should match (see my answer)

Comment: @Max Then why another answer if there already is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258517/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-ruby?

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want to do this with RegEx it looks like you are missing the wildcards neccesary to match anything before and after your actual search term.

```
"The Girl Is Mine (Paul McCartney)".match(/.*The girl is mine.*/i)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aGTEmQ/1